# Ansible handler for restarting Docker Swarm service

Tags: ansible, docker-swarm

I need to restart containers of a Docker Swarm service with Ansible.

The basic definition looks like this:

```yaml
# tasks/main.yml
- name: 'Create the service container'
  docker_swarm_service:
    name: 'service'
    image: 'service'
    networks:
      - name: 'internet'
      - name: 'reverse-proxy'
    publish:
      - { target_port: '80', published_port: '80', mode: 'ingress' }
      - { target_port: '443', published_port: '443', mode: 'ingress' }
      - { target_port: '8080', published_port: '8080', mode: 'ingress' }
    mounts:
      - { source: '{{ shared_dir }}', target: '/shared' }
    replicas: 1
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.role == manager
    restart_config:
      condition: 'on-failure'
    user: null
    force_update: yes
```

So I thought that

```yaml
# handlers/main.yml
- name: 'Restart Service'
  docker_swarm_service:
    name: some-service
    image: 'some-image'
    force_update: yes
```

should work as a handler but it seems that it's not taking all options.
So any advice how to *properly* restart containers of a Docker Swarm service?